# How to remove all tabs from TabView?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I have a simple code to remove all tabs from TabView but as you can see some tabs are still there. So I need advice how to remove all tabs properly.

Playground example http://tinyurl.com/k33r6nz

Or maybe better is to recreate a TabView, isn't?

Comment: 2 things. 1st; in the i < pages.lenght loop, the length decreases with every page you remove. So we need to have the page length stored before we use it in the for loop. 2nd; addressing the remove with page[i] causes the same problem. just keep removing page[0] in each itteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you modify the array you are iterating over:

```js
var pages=container.getChildren();

for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++){
  container.remove(pages[i]);
}
```

`pages` is a reference to the array that gets modified by the `.remove()` action. So when removing *pages[0]* all elements in the *pages* array are shifted to the left. What was *pages[1]* becomes *pages[0]* and with the next round accessing *pages[1]* is what used to be *pages[2]*. So every other element is skipped. You'd better create a copy of the array like

```js
var pages=qx.lang.Array.clone(container.getChildren());
...
```

and it works. The *pages.length* expression is not an issue anymore as the iteration target is not modified in the loop. I think this is also cleaner than always removing *pages[0]* (as suggested in a question comment). Here is a slightly modified version of your code:
http://tinyurl.com/lexwry5

As for re-creating the TabView, it is generally better to keep existing widgets around and reuse them if possible, rather than destroying and re-creating them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing one page at a time you can remove all at once by calling _removeAll() method.
link to the code http://tinyurl.com/pa6ct7r

Answer (score 0):

maybe is a bit (lot) late, but since `pages` is a reference, you can also iterate it with a while:

```
var pages = container.getChildren();
while (pages.length > 0) {
    container.remove(pages[0]);
}
```